# SharePoint SE column formatting - customRowAction, setValue

Tags: sharepoint-server, column-formatting

I've read that SharePoint SE now support custom row actions (feature update 22H2). I do have this update installed but still cannot get the CustomRowAction "setValue" to work. Still not supported?

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "[$FieldName]",
  "customRowAction":{
    "action": "setValue",
    "actionInput": {
      "FieldInternalName_1": "FieldValue_1",
      "FieldInternalName_2": "FieldValue_2"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try adding `"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",` to JSON? Also, you have to use correct **internal name** of column in JSON to show txtContent properly. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using that schema and the correct internal names already.

Comment: Are you using "Early release" or "Standard release"? I think it is available in "Early release". Try changing "Feature release preference" in Central administration to "Early release": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/feature-release-rings#selecting-feature-release-preference

Comment: Yes, I am using early release (confirmed).